# Div Containers auto height

Tags: html, dynamic, height

I have a big problem with my `div` containers.

I have a container that the text is located in and it has dynamic height and there's a container with an icon that is supposed to adjust the height of the text. But the Container with the icon has a fixed height.

Here the link to Fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Reick/uNV8G/)

Comment: Can you please be more clear with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` display attributes to get what you wanted.

CSS:

```
.div-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    border:3px solid #333;
}
.div-table .div-table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.div-table .text-cell {
    width:80%;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
.div-table .icon-cell {
    width:20%;
    background:#999;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:4em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/uNV8G/2/

Comment: Yeah, thats what i need. But the container with the icon musst have a fixed width:85px. I try something - see at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Reick/uNV8G/3/
Thanks a lot =)